# Cloud Firestore - Range Query - paginate data with cursor - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, range

Looks like it is not possible to query a data range in Cloud Firestore.

What I am trying to do is the following ( reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

```
citiesRef.orderBy("population").startAt([1000000]).endAt([2000000]);
```

Unfortunately, this is not working in a not-in compound query.

Here are some examples of what is working for me and what is not.

****Example 1** - whereNotIn + orderBy**

collection.where('user.id', whereNotIn: blackList).orderBy('user.id').orderBy('user.age')

*This is working* and is giving me : id1 age 29, id2 age 33 as expected.

**Example 2 - orderBy + startAt + endAt**

```
collection.orderBy('user.age').startAt([28]).endAt([31]);
```

*This is working*  and is giving me : id1 age 29.

**Example 3 - whereNotIn + orderBy + startAt + endAt**

```
collection.where('user.id', whereNotIn: blackList).orderBy('user.id').orderBy('user.age').startAt([28]).endAt([31]);
```

**This is not working**. I would expect to get just: id1, age 29 but I get no results instead.

My guess is that startAt and endAt are not working with a not-in compound query. I hope to be wrong. Let me know if you have the chance to try it yourself.

NB1: In case you are wondering, the square brackets in the startAt() and endAt() methods are required in Flutter as these methods take a list of values. My current Flutter version is Flutter 2.4.0-4.0.pre.

Cheers

Comment: "Unfortunately, this is not working." Why not? What is the problem with the code you shared? Is there an error message? Is its behavior not what you expected?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your quick feedback. It's a good news it should work, I am doing something wrong then. Actually, I am not getting any error but Is the behaviour which is puzzling me. Here are more details: 

collection.where('user.id', whereNotIn: blackList).orderBy('user.id').orderBy('user.age')

is giving me :
id1 age 29, id2 age33.

but if I add startAt and endAt:

collection.where('user.id', whereNotIn: blackList).orderBy('user.id').orderBy('user.age').startAt([28]).endAt([31]);

I would expect to get just: id1, age 29 but I get no results instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that code and its output in a more readable form? There's an edit link right under it for that precise reason.

Answer (score 0):

--Edit--

You can run whereNotIn and startAt()/endAt() individually, but when you do it in a combined query, startAt() and endAt() takes FIRST orderBy(). That is, in this case it takes the value of user.id. As your user.id doesn’t have the values ‘28’ and ‘31’, it doesn’t return any result.

Comment: Hi Zeenath, thanks for your time! I updated my post to answer your points and provide more details on the issue.